# query omitting null values when using a filter on a column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting 2 different results for the below queries:

```
select op, count(*) from 
(select *, 
 rank() over(partition by  a, b, c order by t desc) as r 
 from table) a 
where r = 1 group by 1
```

[image: Results including null values]

```
select op, count(*) 
from 
(select *, 
 rank() over(partition by  a, b, c order by t desc) as r 
 from table) a 
where r = 1 and op != 'D' group by 1:
```

[image: results omitting null values]

I am wondering why this is happening. Why are `null` values of `op` column being omitted in the second query?

any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to think about this problem from a logical perspective. When using a comparison condition, you can expect three evaluations:

1. True
2. False
3. Unknown

Remember that `NULL` technically isn't a row value. It is essentially a placeholder for when a value is not known, hence the `UNKNOWN` designation. Since the value technically doesn't exist (`UNKNOWN` aka `NULL`), then evaluation will result in `UNKNOWN`. Why? Because how could you logically compare a `KNOWN` value with one that **does not exist.** When a evaluation results in an `UNKNOWN` it is typically treated a FALSE, thus it is excluded from your result set.

**LOGIC EXAMPLE:**

1. A != D evaluates to TRUE.
2. D != D evaluates to FALSE.
3. `null` != D evaluates to `UNKNOWN`
4. NVL(`null`, 'N/A') !=D evaluates to TRUE.

**Here's a nice explanation/example from [Oracle Documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Nulls.html#GUID-29B6554B-C948-4A8E-81C1-696A5128AAAD)**

```
| Condition         | Value of A    | Evaluation    |
|---------------    |------------   |------------   |
| a IS NULL         | 10            | FALSE         |
| a IS NOT NULL     | 10            | TRUE          |
| a IS NULL         | NULL          | TRUE          |
| a IS NOT NULL     | NULL          | FALSE         |
| a = NULL          | 10            | UNKNOWN       |
| a != NULL         | 10            | UNKNOWN       |
| a = NULL          | NULL          | UNKNOWN       |
| a != NULL         | NULL          | UNKNOWN       |
| a = 10            | NULL          | UNKNOWN       |
| a != 10           | NULL          | UNKNOWN       |
```

Answer (score 1):

NULL's are the lack of something being there, so compare differently.

```
select 
    $1 as input
    ,$1 = 'D' as equal_d
    ,$1 != 'D' as not_d
    ,$1 is null as is_null
    ,NOT($1 = 'D') as not_equal_d
    ,($1 is null OR $1 != 'D') as logic1
    ,nvl($1,'') != 'D' as logic2
from values 
('A'),('D'),(null);
```

[image]

shows some simple tests, and effectively how to work around it, with [NVL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl?utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=serp&utm_term=NVL) or COALESCE and other utilities.